# Is there a way to restore the original _layouts/application.master page in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-2007, restore

assuming there is no backup of the original, can I restore application.master file in the _layouts directory in MOSS 2007 back to the default spec?  Either that or does anyone have a copy of the default application.master file that they can share? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[download here from my server](http://www.dcubed.nl/application.zip). P.S. this goes to show you should NEVER edit out of the box sharepoint files. Copy them, then customize the copy and use that in your site.

Comment: in my case probably more than once -D.